# how to get count(*) the right way in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I tried to `count()` the data from database with php but it don't show me the total data but it show the datas.

this is how I count

```
$query = "SELECT 
        mitra.*,         
        user.username, 
        user.privilege, 
        user.name 
    FROM 
        mitra
    INNER JOIN 
        user ON mitra.id_user = user.id "

$result = $connection->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    foreach ($result as $row) :
        $id = "" . $row["id"] . "";
        $total = "" . $row["total_puas"] . "";
        $privilege = "" . $row["privilege"] . "";

        if ($privilege == 2) :
            $calculate = $total / count($id);
            var_dump(count($id));
        endif;
    endforeach;
}

===================
=   id =  total   =
=  1   =   45.84  =
=  2   =   75.45  =
=  3   =   34.54  =
===================
```

when I var_dumb it it shows `int(1)int(1)int(1)` not `int(3)` that what I wanted.

actually I want to count `$calculate` with the data in `$total` that should be there is float and the amount from `$total` that I want to divided with `count id`

is there any solution that how to count the amount from `$total` and can be devided with `count $id` that should be 3?. please help

what I really trying to do from that table example is like `45.84 + 75.45 + 34.54 / 3`

Comment: please show your table structure and expected out put.

Comment: Also please, post the query you do to the database.

Comment: the table should be like above

Comment: and the query I think it's already right because I actually get the data just like `SELECT * FROM table`. I just don't really understand how take the data to be calculate

Comment: What is "total_puas" in your table? Please try to show the table structure. Or can we consider that your table have two fields id and total?

Comment: yes you can consider like that. it is float in total and the id is only int like usual

Comment: I just want to get the data to count it like `$total[0] + $total[1] + $total[3] / 3` and get the result after calculate that but with the data that always be updated because it not always 3 and the $total value are not the same. but when I take the  number of count($id) it is not `3` but `111`

Comment: _Side note:_ You should try and be consistent when writing code. You're currently mixing the "standard" style `if (...) {...}` and the alternative style `if (...): ... endif;`. Things like that makes your code harder to read.

Comment: @QWithOnly, the statement $result->num_rows is the total count of the returned result. You don't have to calculate the count again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$total =0.00;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()):
       if ($row["privilege"] == 2) :
          $total = $total + $row["total"];
          $i++;
       endif;
    endwhile;
    echo $total."<br>";
    echo $i."<br>";
    echo  $calculate = $total / $i;
}

?>

output
=====================================
 $total = 155.83;
 $i = 3;
 $calculate = $total/$i;
 $ans = 51.943333333333;
=====================================
```

Comment: it has the same output when `var_dump(count($result))`

Comment: it actually work it can take the data with `$result->num_rows` but it get `4` because I only need the data when `privilege=2` which is 3 right now. and it repeating get the data 3 times because I put in in `if privilege=2`

Comment: actually I want to calculate 45.84 + 75.45 + 34.54 / 3. is it possible?

Comment: it actually works but it says `Undefined variable: total in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/.......` do you have any idea why?

Comment: sorry sir, not any idea

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` in your query. Doing `count($id)` in PHP will always yield one, as its not an array of values.

```php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt, id, total_puas
          FROM table
          GROUP BY id";

$result = $connection->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $calculate = $row["total_puas"] / $row['cnt'];
        echo $row['id']." has a count of ".$row['cnt'].", a total of ".$row['total_puas']." and calculated to ".$calculate."<br />\n";
    }
}
```

From your updated question, the output becomes a bit more clear. Based on the output data and the result you desire, you want to calculate the sum of all `total_paus`, divided by the number of rows. You can do this directly in one query, like this

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total_puas) / COUNT(u.id) as total
          FROM mitra AS m
          INNER JOIN user AS u
              ON mitra.id_user = user.id";

$result = $connection->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$total = $row['total'];
echo $total;
```

Comment: is it means I have to select the row name 1 by 1? because when I tried sql `SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt, mitra.*, user.username, user.privilege, user.name FROM mitra
INNER JOIN user ON mitra.id_user = user.id ` it ambiguous

Comment: `id` is ambigious in the `COUNT()`, so for you, with the join, it should be `COUNT(user.id)` (or any other column, the row-count is the same anyways).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table"
$result = $connection->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $total = 0.0;
    foreach ($result as $row) :
        $id = "" . $row["id"] . "";
        $total = $total + $row['total'];
    endforeach;
    $calculate = $total / $result->num_rows;
    echo $total.<br>;
    echo $calclulate;
}
```